# Update Scope With SetInterval / SetTimeout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a "Clock" directive as a way to learn Angular. How would I go about making sure it "ticks?"

Here's what I tried [fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pharylon/oafcde6g/9/):

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('clock' , function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>{{date}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
      scope.date = getDate();
      setInterval(function(){
        scope.date = getDate();
      }, 100);
    }
  }
})
```

Using setInterval to upate the scope variable isn't working. I'm assuming because the directive isn't watching for it to be changes anymore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is updating the scope variable, but Angular isn't aware of the change.

It is recommended to use Angular [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Here is your fiddle with `$interval`: https://jsfiddle.net/oafcde6g/11/

In other words, Angular doesn't do any magic by "listening" to scope properties, it simply does dirty-checking. But to do it, it needs to be notified that something changed. So if you really wanted to use `setInterval` instead of `$interval`, you could notify it manually that something changed:

```
setInterval(function () {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.date = getDate();
    });
});
```

This way, you're notifying it to run your anonymous function inside `$apply` and then digest the scope, checking if anything changed. If it did, it will update the view.

#### "Magic" of ng-* events (ng-click, ng-model etc)

Even though it looks like angular automatically knows to rerender the view when you click/change something by using it's built-in directives, it really isn't so.

Some simple implementation of `ng-click` would look something like:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('ngClick' , function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
        elem.on('click', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.$eval(attr.ngClick);
            });
        });
    }
  }
})
```

You can see this for yourself if you try to bind click event normally, outside of angular context and make it change a scope variable. It won't update until you explicitly tell it to (like we did in `setInterval` example).